# Recommendations for linux hosting

Tags: ruby, linux, node.js, hosting

I'm about to embark on a new project which will require linux hosting, so I was hoping for some recommendations.  The full technology stack is yet to be finalised, but it very likely to feature: nodejs, ruby and some form of NoSql(couchDB/mongoDB).

As well as supporting a variety of technologies, the hosting also needs to be scalable.  Also,  it could do with being as cheap as possible.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Iain

Answer (score 3):

From my personal experience I highly recommend [Linode](http://linode.com/). They're probably the best on the VPS market. If you don't mind starting with a little bigger server, you can try [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2), which is also a great service.

I haven't had a single problem with Linode in over 2 years, and every time I needed something on tech support, the reply was almost instant.